# How to add custom file system metadata on RTF file in Alfresco?

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to add custom file system metadata on rtf file using Apache POI API.
But later I found that POI is not supporting rtf file.

Can anybody help me which API should I use ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/rtf/RTFEditorKit.html

Comment: thanks Krutik. I checked it but Still it does not provide any API to add custom file system metadata.